# Probability measures and dirac measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convex-analysis, dirac-delta

Let $X$ be a compact set.

Consider the set $H$ of non-negative probability measure $\eta$ defined on $X$ satisfying 
$$
\eta(dx) = \delta_\xi(dx),\quad \xi \in X.
$$

How to understand, how to expect that
$$
\overline{\text{conv}}(H) = \{\text{probability measure}\}?
$$

Comment: What does $dx$ mean?

Comment: @uniquesolution That's just a funny notation - some people write $\int f(x)\mu(dx)$ for what I would write as $\int f(x)\,d\mu(x)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich And they have good reasons for that. In a sort of way the "infinitely small"  $dx$ is "measured" which is expressed in $\mu(dx)$ (not $x$).

Comment: @drhab I don't like it, but it makes more sense than it did, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $B$ is the set of all Borel probability measures on $X$. Then $B$ is convex, and $B$ is compact in the weak* topology (regarding measures as elements of $C(X)^*$.) So $B$ is the weak* closed convex hull of its extreme points, by Choquet's theorem. It's not hard to show that the extreme points of $B$ are exactly the measures in $H$.